# Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK when integrating Espresso and Ant

Tags: java, android, ant, android-espresso

I'm attempting to integrate Espresso into my project without using the standalone jar (using that created issues with dexing).  However, I'm running int a problem in that the LICENSE.txt of `hamcrest-library-1.1.jar` and `hamcrest-core-1.1.jar` is identical, causing Ant to give me the error message "Duplicate files at the same path inside the APK".

The Espresso website provides a workaround for this if you're using Gradle, but we're building using Ant, so that's of no help. Are there any similar workaround for Ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ant you can repack the jar excluding the LICENSE.txt file like this:

```
<move file="libs/hamcrest-core.jar" tofile="libs/hamcrest-core-in.jar" />
<jar destfile="libs/hamcrest-core.jar">
    <zipfileset src="libs/hamcrest-core-in.jar" excludes="LICENSE.txt"/>
</jar>
<delete file="libs/hamcrest-core-in.jar"/>
```

Do this for all three files and the dex problem is gone.